# Wordpress - Call AWS APIs

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, wordpress-rest-api

I am completely new to wordpress. I need to perform some AWS api(like list instances, create user and so on) calls in wordpress. What is the best way to do this action.

I have installed PHP SDK in my machine(Ubuntu) and I could call AWS vendor folder in a single file in my local folder, but not in wordpress.

Is there anyway to install AWS API plugin in wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

If there's an official plugin maintained by Amazon, they will tell you about it on their documentation pages. For user contributed plugins please have a look at the WordPress plugin directory:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/aws (search by tag)

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=aws (search by keyword)

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides an official SDK for PHP here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html

You can find the GitHub repository with examples here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/

The next step is to include this library into a Wordpress plugin template using composer, autoload the classes and start.

**Edit**

Alternatively there is this free API Wrapper containing an up-to-date version of the above mentioned AWS SDK:

https://wordpress.recuweb.com/installer/amazon-web-services/

And this is an implementation tutorial to integration the SDK as a dependency in a bigger development project:

https://code.recuweb.com/2022/integrating-an-aws-service-into-a-wp-plugin-boilerplate/